# Posting an article containing mathematical symbols and R code

Tags: posts

I have been trying to figure out the best workflow to publish articles heavy in R code and R output and mathematical formulas.
I would like to be able to finish the entire report in RMarkdown including all the figures (ggplot), code and tables (kable). So far I tried to copy the html code from RStudio and pasted it directly into the text editor of Wordpress. When doing that I get the following errors:

1. Basically everything that is in the <head> tag in the html file will offset the beginning my article by a certain margin. You can not see the code but I can see extra whitespace added at the beginning. The rest is displayed normally.
2. I noticed that tables produced with kable() cannot be displayed. What could be the reason? Is there an alternative?

I imagine what I could do is to generate my tables in html and define my own styling options. This process still does not appear very streamlined to me. I would love to hear what ideas you have.

Comment: Just as a suggestion; why not simply make a screenshot of your R stuff and attach that as featured image of the according post? And then, when displaying the post, call the featured image of that post?

Comment: I forget what they're called but there are plugins out there that allow for advanced formatting of mathematical formulas.

Comment: One solution that I somewhat like is to use GitHub gist. I still need to find a way to also include the output of a command. I would have to look at the html file again generated by knitr and see if I can extract individual components.